# Email sent with telnet, But not with SMTLIB python script[Organization Mail / Not Gmail]

Tags: python, python-2.7, server, smtp, telnet

i am trying to write a script to send attachments inside an email using my organization Email! i tried first just telnet and it worked fine!

```
    >helo username@company.net
    >mail from:<username@company.net>
    >rcpt to:<username@company.net>
    >data
    >From: username@company.net
    >Subject: test mail from command line

    >this is test number 1
    >sent from linux box
    >.
    >quit
```

But when i tried to use a .py script, i faced some issues :

Here is my code

```py
    import smtplib  
    fromaddr = 'naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net' 
    toaddrs  =  'naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net'
    msg = 'Hello'  
    # The actual mail send  
    server = smtplib.SMTP('sddlogin',25)  
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.ehlo()
    print("ok ehlo")
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg) 
    print("email sent") 
    server.quit()
```

And i got a relay access denied : here is the logs :

````py
    send: 'ehlo [172.20.0.11]\r\n'
    reply: '250-sddlogin.frcl.bull.fr\r\n'
    reply: '250-PIPELINING\r\n'
    reply: '250-SIZE 10240000\r\n'
    reply: '250-VRFY\r\n'
    reply: '250-ETRN\r\n'
    reply: '250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
    reply: '250-8BITMIME\r\n'
    reply: '250 DSN\r\n'
    reply: retcode (250); Msg: sddlogin.frcl.bull.fr
    PIPELINING
    SIZE 10240000
    VRFY
    ETRN
    ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    8BITMIME
    DSN
    ok ehlo
    send: 'mail FROM:<naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net> size=5\r\n'
    reply: '250 2.1.0 Ok\r\n'
    reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.1.0 Ok
    send: 'rcpt TO:<naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net>\r\n'
    reply: '554 5.7.1 <naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net>: Relay access denied\r\n'
    reply: retcode (554); Msg: 5.7.1 <naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net>: Relay access denied
    send: 'rset\r\n'
    reply: '250 2.0.0 Ok\r\n'
    reply: retcode (250); Msg: 2.0.0 Ok
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/gpfs/work/nbrahmi/utils/mcook/dev-r3.12/test/system_tests/light_nonregression/env_vrm_mode/send_email.py", line 10, in <module>
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg) 
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 746, in sendmail
        raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
    smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net': (554, '5.7.1 <naoufal.brahmi.external@atos.net>: Relay access denied')}

```python
````

Comment: the server is passwordless since my ssh key already installed! so i just ssh directly, that's why i am not using server.login!

Comment: Your mail server does not care about your ssh key. You are connecting to ddlogin.frcl.bull.fr and try to deliver to an atos.net address. Hence the ddlogin.frcl.bull.fr  sees that the atos.net address is not local, i.e., not on the french server, and it refuses to relay the email as not to be misused by spammers. Connect either to your email provder's smtp server, or straight to atos.net.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I also got the same error. This is occured due to Google's new security policy. To remove this error I had gone to Security.google.com -> Security -> Less Secure Apps -> Turn it on.
You are good to go

Comment: Thanks danish, but i am using a server and email company not google !